How to get latest child table id based on condition
I am writing one query to get results based on parent table records and latest child table id based on condition
Sample Data:
*Department*

Id  Name 
-----------
1   Dept1
2   Dept2
3   Dept3
4   Dept4

*Employee*

Id DeptId  quality   VerifiedOn
----------------------------------
1    1      Ok        '2014-08-01'
2    2      Ok        '2014-09-01'
3    2      Best      '2014-08-01'
4    2      Good      '2014-08-07'
5    4      Good      '2014-10-08'
6    4      Ok        '2014-10-01'
7    4      Good      '2014-09-01'

Requirement
I need to get all department details along with latest good quality employee Id.
Good Quality Employee logic is :

Take Latest employeeId of Quality is 'Best'
If not Best quality is there, take latest of employeeId
If no employee available for the department return 0 or NULL

[top 1 order by VerifiedOn desc]
Need to create viwew for this
Expected Result:
DeptId DeptName EmpiId
-----------------------
  1     Dept1     1
  2     Dept2     3
  3     Dept3     0
  4     Dept4     5


I have created this fiddle to help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/hCuJf6Mt

I've contributed to this fiddle and wrote the query that works for you. Hope it helps :)

@Salt you have to post the new link, fiddles are read only for some reason :) Or even better, just post the answer!

Thanks @siggemannen, here is the new fiddle! https://dbfiddle.uk/QfxElg1b

actually i forget to include that the result i want to create as view . So anything other cte is good. I like the approach @siggemannen told

you can use ctes in view though :)

This should do the trick:
WITH cteEmployee As
(
  SELECT
      Id,
      DeptId,
      quality,
      VerifiedOn,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (
          PARTITION BY 
              DeptId 
          ORDER BY 
              CASE quality WHEN 'Best' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
              VerifiedOn DESC
      ) As RN
  FROM
      Employee
)
SELECT
  D.Id,
  D.Name,
  E.Id,
  E.quality,
  E.VerifiedOn
FROM
    Department As D
    LEFT JOIN cteEmployee As E ON E.DeptId = D.Id And E.RN = 1
ORDER BY
  D.Name
;

Results:



Id
Name
Id
quality
VerifiedOn




1
Dept1
1
Ok
2014-08-01


2
Dept2
3
Best
2014-08-01


3
Dept3
null
null
null


4
Dept4
5
Good
2014-10-08



ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL) - SQL Server | Microsoft Learn

I used 3 sub queries to search for the employees.
SELECT d.*, 
  COALESCE
  (
    (SELECT top 1 e.ID 
     FROM Employee e 
     WHERE e.deptID=d.Id AND e.quality='Best' 
     ORDER BY VerifiedOn desc),
    (SELECT top 1 e.ID 
     FROM Employee e 
     WHERE e.deptID=d.Id AND e.quality='Good' 
     ORDER BY VerifiedOn desc),
    (SELECT top 1 e.ID 
     FROM Employee e 
     WHERE e.deptID=d.Id AND e.quality='Ok' 
     ORDER BY VerifiedOn desc), 
    '0'
  ) as EmpiId
FROM Department d
GROUP BY d.ID,d.Name

Alternative suggested by Siggemannen:
SELECT d.*, 
  ISNULL  
  ( 
   (SELECT top 1 e.ID 
   FROM Employee e 
   WHERE e.deptID=d.Id 
   ORDER BY CASE  e.quality
            WHEN 'Best' THEN 0
            WHEN 'Good' THEN 1
            WHEN 'OK' THEN 2
            Else 3
            END,
            VerifiedOn desc),
   0
  )  as EmpiId
FROM Department d
GROUP BY d.ID,d.Name

fiddle



Id
Name
EmpiId




1
Dept1
1


2
Dept2
3


3
Dept3
0


4
Dept4
5




why not just do order by case quality when 'best' then 0 when 'good' then 1 when 'ok' then 2 else 3 end, verifiedon desc?

@siggemannen That is another option. You should post that as an answer.

The CASE expression is not needed as the provided sort is identic to the alphabetic one, so you can just remove that and rather simply write ...ORDER BY e.quality...

@Jonas Metzler This CASE is required so the solution works even after the data is translated to another language :)

In this situation, it would also fail because all rows would take the ELSE clause ;)

I tested the query on a DB Fiddle on MySQL v9 and I got your expected results.
What this does: I use ROW_NUMBER() and PARTITION BY e.DeptID to rank the employees in each department.
Then I sorted them first by Quality and secondly by VerifiedOn
This allows me with rn = 1 to return only the latest "Good Quality" employee from every department
On the Final SELECT its just a LEFT JOIN between both.
To ensure departments with no employee who meets the requirements COALESCE(le.EmpID,0) replaces any NULL values with 0
  WITH LatestEmployee AS (
        SELECT 
            e.Id AS EmpId,
            e.DeptId,
            e.Quality,
            e.VerifiedOn,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY e.DeptId
                ORDER BY 
                    CASE WHEN e.Quality = 'Best' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
                    e.VerifiedOn DESC
            ) AS rn
        FROM 
            Employee e
    )
    
    SELECT 
        d.Id AS DeptId,
        d.Name AS DeptName,
        COALESCE(le.EmpId, 0) AS EmpId
    FROM 
        Department d
    LEFT JOIN 
        LatestEmployee le ON d.Id = le.DeptId AND le.rn = 1
    ORDER BY 
        d.Id;

